# Golang XML Parsing issue

Tags: xml, parsing, go

I have just started experimenting with Google's GO (Golang) language, and have run into a problem that I would like to solve efficiently. 
So I would like to extract some data from an XML file, that is available online (I get it as the response of a polling session), but I don't know how to get started. Should I download the source code of the page, store it locally and extract the data that way or is there a possibility to extract the data without downloading the whole thing? Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its available online you can use `net/http` client to retrieve the xml. Then you can use `encoding/xml` package and convert the response body to struct object, it has `xml.Unmarshal` method to convert xml string to struct - hence you should write the struct first.

`net/http` example available

- https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

`encoding/xml` example

- https://gist.github.com/kwmt/6135123#file-parsetvdb-go